# Designing counter on Verilog with input button

Tags: verilog

I'm creating some counter that counts +1, -1, and +2 with respect to button input 001, 010, 100.

Here is my code.

```
module binary_counter(
        input clk,
        input resetn,
        input [2:0] push, 
        output [3:0] data_out
    );
    
    reg [3:0] data_temp_out;

    always @(posedge clk or negedge resetn) begin   
        if(~resetn) begin
            data_temp_out <= 4'b0;       // all 0
        end
                    
        else if(resetn == 1) begin    // else
            if(push == 3'b001) begin    
                data_temp_out <= data_temp_out +1;    // count +1
            end
            
            else if(push == 3'b010) begin   // count-1
                data_temp_out <= data_temp_out -1;
            end
            
            else if(push == 3'b100) begin   // count+3
                data_temp_out <= data_temp_out +3;
            end
        end
    end
    
    assign data_out = data_temp_out;
    
endmodule
```

With some topModule and clock signal given, I implemented this counter on FPGA board. The `push[2:0]` is connected to three push button. What the problem is, if I keep pressing the button, the count keeps rising.

What I desired was to count only when button input is changed. I mean it only counts +1 even if I keep push button1 (001) and same for other button input.

Can you give me a hint or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the condition `push == 3'b001` is constantly met when you keep pushing button1.

Instead, you can create a `push`-value-change event which is single-cycle pulse, by comparing the current `push` with the last `push`.

```
reg [2:0] push_d;
wire push_chg;
always @(posedge clk or negedge resetn) begin
    if(~resetn) begin
        push_d <= 3'h0;
    end
    else begin
        push_d <= push;
    end
end
assign push_chg = (push != push_d);
```

Then evaluate the `push` value when the above event occurs.

```
            if(push_chg & (push == 3'b001)) begin
                ...
            end
```

Comment: I sincerely thank you all. But what I can't understand is if I add that code on my design source, what I think would happen is that 

since the code that you given occurs on every positive edge or negative edge on resetn, push_d is equal to push and compare push != push_d.

I mean the order of event would be
push button input -> push_d <= push -> push != push_d and it always gives 0.

But to operate properly the order of event would be

push_d <= push -> push input -> push != push_d.

Does second order is correct one? If so, I cannot understand why this operates on that way

Comment: The sequence you gave `push button input -> push_d <= push -> push != push_d`, sounds like a sequentially executed program. No, it's circuit which works in parallel. `push_d` always lag `push` one cycle. By comparing, we can indicate when `push` changes. It may be easier to get a better understanding via waveform.